# Temporary tablespace size in 12C

Tags: oracle-12c, temporary-tables

I have installed 12C and importing data through sqlldr , but it increases the temporary tablespace size tremendously which causing the oracle shutdown.
Please help and guide me what to do to get rid of this issue.

Comment: Give us a reproduceable example?

Comment: I haven't recreated temp tablespace?

Comment: At the moment i just added more temp file to Temp tablespace. TEMP tablespace size is 180GB and 80GB is already full...

Comment: What's in it???

Comment: due to importing data .... it is increasing.....

Comment: Yeah, I think we got that.  Perhaps the free space is diminishing too.

Comment: So what you suggest to do?

Comment: Have a look what is in the Temp tablespace.

Comment: this issue is resolved.... we hv create another tablespace and add datafiles from another location then made it the default temporary tablespace, after that dropped the old one...Now we are fine the issue was the tablespace size.

Comment: too big, too small ???

Comment: we hv increased size from 80 GB to 160GB